# Overcoming CORB restrictions on an old API?

Tags: javascript, xml, cors, transit

Trying to offload some fetching of updated bus positions from the NJTransit API here -- http://mybusnow.njtransit.com/bustime/map/getRoutePoints.jsp?route=87 -- which returns pretty rudimentary XML. No CORS header / policy as best I can tell, so Chrome is throwing an error and blocking the request with a pointer to [this issue tracker](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5629709824032768).

```
route='87';

function logResult(result) {
  console.log(result);
}

function logError(error) {
  console.log('Looks like there was a problem: \n', error);
}

function validateResponse(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw Error(response.statusText);
  }
  return response;
}

function readResponseAsXML(response) {
  let responseDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response, 'application/xml');
  var oSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
  var buses_xml = oSerializer.serializeToString(responseDoc);
  return buses_xml;
}

function fetchXML(pathToResource) {
  fetch(pathToResource, {mode:'no-cors'}) // 1
  .then(validateResponse) // 2
  .then(readResponseAsXML) // 3
  .then(logResult) // 4
  .catch(logError);
}

fetchXML('http://mybusnow.njtransit.com/bustime/map/getRoutePoints.jsp?route='+ route);
```

Is there any way around this? I know it's a browser-based issue, and I can issue the call from the server and it will all be fine, but that's exactly what I'm trying to move away from. The current solution is fetching these updates from the server and passing them through to client via my own server API. I would like to cut myself out as the middleman and just have the clients fetch the updated positions themselves.

The likelihood of getting the data source (NJT) to make any changes to their API setup is very low.

Thanks

Comment: Use a CORS proxy. Example: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Anthony, are you able to reach that URL directly? I've tried(to check if its Content-Type is valid)  but request is failed.

Comment: fixed title. yes the API URL is reachable. been using it for years in my applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this:

```
route='87';

function logResult(result) {
  console.log(result);
}

function logError(error) {
  console.log('Looks like there was a problem: \n', error);
}

function validateResponse(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw Error(response.statusText);
  }
  return response;
}

function readResponseAsXML(response) {
  let responseDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response, 'application/xml');
  var oSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
  var buses_xml = oSerializer.serializeToString(responseDoc);
  return buses_xml;
}

function fetchXML(pathToResource) {
  fetch(pathToResource, {}) // 1
    .then(validateResponse) // 2
    .then(readResponseAsXML) // 3
    .then(logResult) // 4
    .catch(logError);
}

fetchXML('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://mybusnow.njtransit.com/bustime/map/getRoutePoints.jsp?route='+ route);
```

I have changed your code to use CORS proxy.

Please check @ CodePen:
https://codepen.io/animatedcreativity/pen/b5796c4b3711b6f8d6437beff0c2c40a

Example XML response:

```
<route>
        <id>87</id> 
        <rtpiFeedName></rtpiFeedName>
        <sn>87</sn> 
        <nm>87 Jersey City - Hoboken</nm> 
        <displayDesignator>87</displayDesignator> 
        <vmode>1</vmode>   

        <sbs>



        </sbs>

        <c>#ff0033</c>

        <pas>


            <pa>
                <id>3393</id>

                <d>Hoboken</d> 
                <dd>Hoboken</dd>  
                <directionRtpiFeedName></directionRtpiFeedName>

                <pt>
                    <lat>40.692060000000545</lat>
                    <lon>-74.0966800000009</lon>
                    <dtr>false</dtr> 

                    <bs>
                        <id>21028</id>
...
```

Comment: i keep getting 503s but will setup my own cors-anywhere instance and test it out. TYVM!

Comment: @AnthonyTownsend: Did you my check example @ CodePen? Please check the browser console. It is loading XML without any problem.

Comment: yes + i got it working in production on my own cors-anywhere instance. thanks for great help.

Comment: @AnthonyTownsend : I am glad that I could help.